# Only show months that have a blog entry

Tags: low-yearly-archives

I'm just wondering if it's possible to hide all the months that don't have a blog entry?

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="blog" start_month="1" status="not closed" sort="desc"}
  {year}
       {months}
              <li>
              {if num_entries != 0}
              <a href="{path=index.php/corporate/blog}/{year}/{month_num}/" title="{num_entries} entries in {month} {year}">{month_short} ({num_entries})</a>
              {if:else}
              {month_short}
              {/if}
              </li>
       {/months}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

I only have blog entries in the month on July at the moment, but it's showing me every month from January. I may be able to work around this by using "month_start" but, if there's ever a case I miss a month with a blog entry then I wouldn't want the month showing with no archives. Also, if i remove "month_short", it takes away the names, but still leaves a space for the month.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the if:else and you'll only display months with entries

```
 {if num_entries != 0}
        <a href="{path=index.php/corporate/blog}/{year}/{month_num}/" title="{num_entries} entries in {month} {year}">{month_short} ({num_entries})</a>
 {/if}
```

Comment: Nice! That worked. Removing the {if:else} and moving the <li> within the {if} did the trick!